# After Magento upgrade from 1.4 to 1.8 - "Recoverable Errors"

Tags: magento-1.8, upgrade, database

I'm seeing a lot of "Recoverable Errors" in my system.log file after an upgrade from 1.4 to 1.8. For example:

> 2014-09-17T21:57:08+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1
>   passed to Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract::load() must be an
>   instance of Mage_Core_Model_Abstract, array given, called in
>   /chroot/home/site/site.com/html/ecc/Desktop.php on line 61 and defined
>   in
>   /chroot/home/site/site.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php
>   on line 371
>
> 2014-09-17T21:57:08+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1
>   passed to Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract::unserializeFields()
>   must be an instance of Mage_Core_Model_Abstract, array given, called
>   in
>   /chroot/home/site/site.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php
>   on line 387 and defined  in
>   /chroot/home/site/site.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php
>   on line 546
>
> 2014-09-17T21:57:08+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1
>   passed to Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract::_afterLoad() must be
>   an instance of Mage_Core_Model_Abstract, array given, called in
>   /chroot/home/site/site.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php
>   on line 388 and defined  in
>   /chroot/home/site/site.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php
>   on line 697

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Is the site running? This is a third party  /chroot/home/site/site.com/html/ecc/Desktop.php

Comment: Yes, the site is running. We have some minor issues, but it seems to be ok for the most part. I realize the ecc thing is a third party module, but the errors are not only tied to that, as you can see by the 2 samples after that one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's by far the most most likely these are originating from third party modules/customisations.  Even though the file referenced (`app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php`) is a core class, it's an abstract class which means it's never instantiated itself, its only ever extended off by other classes.  This in turn means it won't actually be that class calling the method, it will be a child class which doesn't have the method defined so the call is falling back to the parent abstract class.  As you just aren't going to get core classes passing the wrong data types as arguments to core methods (it's developed better than that) I think the error has to originate from some customisation or third party module.

Did you ensure all third party modules and customisations were upgraded to be compatible with 1.8CE before moving to the new Magento version?

Comment: We were pretty sure we updated all modules, but it's definitely possible we missed one or two. This client had a ton of modules installed. Thanks for the pointer.